# Sharing serial device

Tags: linux

I'm running Ubuntu and I need to share a serial device (`/dev/ttyUSB0`) using `socat` or something like it.

Here is my diagram:

```
                              /--</dev/ttyUSB01>--[Process A]
[serial device]-/dev/ttyUSB0--
                              \--</dev/ttyUSB02>--[Process B]
```

Both process A and B need to read-write, no problem about concurrency.

How can I create a two "virtual" devices like `/dev/ttyUSB01` and `/dev/ttyUSB02`?

Answer (score 2):

Following and [advice at StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093446/share-serial-port-on-linux), have you ever tried to use the same device designation to both processes?

Or, do you have any special need to create both 2 pseudo-devices so processes access virtual "different" serial ports? If yes, I'll do this udev symlink trick with my 3gModem, but it can be applied to other devices. Remember, they are still links to the same device. Using `dmesg` i found that my modem is `/dev/ttyUSB0`:

```
[  224.777566] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[  224.778326] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[  224.779065] option 1-1:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  224.780923] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Determine the full device path(ugly name):

```
[root@localhost ~]# udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
```

With the full device path, get all information. You will have a very long screen information list so, I paste just the relevant information:

```
[root@localhost ~]# udevadm info -a -p /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="option1"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"
```

Now, it is just to create 2 aliases on Udev with the information extracted on the last command. I'll create a file called `50-modem.rules` at `/etc/udev/rules.d`. You can name it whatever you want as long as it ends with ".rules", but use the starting number 50 as an advice.

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial",DRIVERS=="option1",ATTRS{port_number}=="0",SYMLINK+="3gmodem0"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial",DRIVERS=="option1",ATTRS{port_number}=="0",SYMLINK+="3gmodem1"
```

Trigger the udev rules and you are good to go:

```
[root@localhost rules.d]# udevadm trigger 
[root@localhost rules.d]# ls -l /dev/3g*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Mar 25 19:55 /dev/3gmodem0 -> ttyUSB1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Mar 25 19:55 /dev/3gmodem1 -> ttyUSB1
```